# Can İ change my files in hosting with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, hosting

I have built my  first website.  But there are lots of problems, for example when I click poster of article, the data of the clicked poster  are loaded to local storage and  the opening html page takes  these data from local storage and shows. But in that case  the unique URL is not generated. every  article page has ending article.html. They just loads different data when I click it's poster.  I  thought maybe there is a way to create  new  unique html page in your hosting file management system, with Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way for client-side JavaScript, on its own, to create files on a website.

If this was possible then every major website would find all its content overwritten with whatever random passers by felt like storing.

JavaScript can make HTTP requests to a server (e.g. with the `fetch` API). You can then process the content of the request with server-side code (written in any programming language you like and that your hosting service supports).